# Loader isn't spinning when it's inside flex container

Tags: css, reactjs, safari, flexbox, semantic-ui

I'm using [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) library to build my React app. I'm using a [Loader](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/loader.html), and somewhere in my component I have something like this:

```
if (loading) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="ui active inline loader" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and everything works fine. However, Loader is not centered in the div, so I modified wrapper div to be like `<div className="centered"`>, where:

```
.centered {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Now, Loader is centered but is not spinning **in Safari browser**! How can solve it?

In Chrome it works fine.

Comment: CSS3 animations can be very wonky in Safari.  Not an ideal solution, but have you tried placing it in a div with the ```ui active dimmer``` classes that come with Semantic? That should center it, I took a peek and they have a lot of webkit prefixed properties that may address whatever issue you're experiencing, and you could override the default styles to get the effect you need.

Comment: Your css class seems to be misspelled. alignItems: center; should be align-items: center; justifyContant: center; should be justify-content: center;

Comment: sorry, @henrik123 that was a typo error. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the centring issue, you may need the webkits:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Then just humour me on the animation, is it done using a CSS animation (keyframes)? If you are you may have missed out the last leg of the animation and forgotten the 100% keyframe? I think this has tripped me up before.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your spinner inside another div. 
I used Bootstrap-Vue for the example, but I think the concept is very clear.

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
     <div>
       <b-spinner v-show="isLoading" variant="success" label="Spinning" />
     </div>
     <p>Test Test Test</p>
</div>
```